# Aguardar finalização da thread antes de encerrar o programa

Tags: python, thread, loop

Tenho um *loop* `while` que finaliza somente quando aperto a tecla *q*, então o programa é encerrado. Dentro desse *loop*, em determinado momento ou condição, inicio uma **thread** que demora mais ou menos uns *10* segundos para executar.

Meu problema é, se saio do *loop* apertando *q* com uma *thread* em execução, esta é cancelada.

Eu gostaria que o *loop/script* aguardasse a execução da *thread*, para depois finalizar o programa. É possível isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Cara, poderia colocar a parte relevante do seu código? Acho que fica meio abstrato sem nada do código...

Comment: Mas, possivelmente, usando um [`thread.isAlive()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive) resolva o seu problema...

Comment: @FelipeAvelar, obrigado pelo retorno. Eu posso até usar o thread.isAlive() para detectar se existe, mas como "esperar" o encerramento da thread? Ah, outra coisa, percebi que mesmo encerrando o programa e voltando para o prompt, a thread continua executando até finalizar, de certa forma isso é bom, só queria que aguardasse para voltar ao prompt.

Comment: Poderia colocar um `while thread.isAlive(): pass`. Mas eu não posso afirmar com precisão, sem ver o código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Além do modo [mencionado pelo Felipe Avelar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55889/aguardar-finaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-thread-antes-de-encerrar-o-programa-python#comment114921_55889) usando o método [`Thread.is_alive()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive), há também o método [`Thread.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join). Ambos podem ser utilizados em conjunto.

Quando [`Thread.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) é chamado, diz a *thread* principal para esperar que uma determinada *thread* termine, antes que a *thread* principal prossiga e execute a próxima instrução. Segue um exemplo:

```py
import time, threading

def fun():
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)

def main():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=fun)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
    # A thread foi finalizada, fazer algo a partir daqui
    print("Thread finalizada")

main()
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/H2eGBb)</kbd>